# Call Java Spring Rest Api from Postman to EC2

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I placed a JAR file inside the ec2 instance and start it by using the following command
`java -jar abc.java`
I opened another ssh window and try to call the API endpoint, it fetched data successfully. However, when I am trying to call it from my local machine or Postman it gives me the error of **Could not connect to the requested server host.**
Following are my ec2 inbound rules. How can I call my rest endpoint. any help would be appriciated.
[image]

Comment: First rule's ip (::/0) refer to ipv6 addresses, try with 0.0.0.0/0 (all ipv4 addresses), are you sure that from your local machine you are pointing to the right ip?

Comment: @rentox98 when I am assigning 0.0.0.0/0 it gives me the error that You may not specify an IPv4 CIDR for an existing IPv6 CIDR rule.

Comment: Try to add another rule for ipv4, read this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-web-server

Comment: @rentox98 Thanks for this document. It helps me to solve my problem.

Comment: You're Welcome, how did you solve it?